# Bold text in the from field: <input>?

Tags: html, input, google-calendar-api, font-face

Today when I filled my calendar at google  I saw that the description of the event is in bold font:

```
<input id=":g" name=":g" type="text" class="textinput" dir="ltr">
```

Is it possible to render the custom text style in the text input field?

Thanks 
Arman.

**EDIT**
Simple search I fond that the  [jquery watermark](http://daersystems.com/jquery/watermark/) plugin can do similar thing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

CSS can format text in text input field:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   input {font-weight:bold;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="text"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

try this you don't need to write css

```
 <input type="text" style="font-weight: bold;">
```

Comment: yeah... but its an alternate way for few styles we can write inline css

Comment: Indeed. I was only commenting on your "you don't need to write css" remark.

Comment: But.. Isn't `font-weight: bold` CSS? :D

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap 5.0 you can use "fw-bold"