# How do i make font bold in a form block?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code for a text box where users type their own text. But I need the font to be bold. How can I do this using CSS?

```
<form>
    Enter Text:<br>
    <input type="text" name="your text" id="entertext">
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bold text in the from field: <input>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323508/bold-text-in-the-from-field-input)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```css
form {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form>
      Enter Text:<br>
      <input type="text" name="your text" id="entertext">
   </form>
```

But I would advice you to use a `label` for the input field and style that. Otherwise the rest of your form will also be bold (assuming you will add more to the form)

```css
form label {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<form>
      <label for="entertext">Enter Text:</label>
      <input type="text" name="your text" id="entertext">
   </form>
```

For more info check [HTML  Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Use this css:

```
form {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you want only the text the user will input to be bold, go for:

```
form input {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**EDIT**

Something like this could work, but it requires jQuery:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>

<form id="form">
    Enter Text:<br>
    <input type="text" name="your text" id="entertext"><br />
    <button id="toggle">Toggle Weight</button>
</form>

<script>    
    jQuery('#toggle').on('click', function(e) {
      jQuery('#form input[type="text"]').toggleClass("bold"); //you can list several class names 
      e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks this has worked. is it possible if you could show me how to make a button where it then toggles the font from normal font to bold

Comment: Check my EDIT! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
form {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
form input {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter Text:<br>
  <input type="text" name="your-text" id="entertext">
</form>
```

As a note: the name attribute of your input shouldn't contain a space. If you want this as your placeholder text use the placeholder attribute like: `<input type="text" name="your-text" id="entertext" placeholder="Your Text">`

Answer (score 0):

try below CSS

```
input[type=text]{font-weight:bold}
```