# Making variable text bold

Tags: javascript

```
  var text1 = "Mind";
  var text2 = document.getElementById("t1").value;
  var text3 = text1.concat(text2);
  document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML = text3;
```

I want to make the text of variable "text2" in bold when displayed, Please tell how I can do that...

Comment: You can wrap `text2` in an HTML element and apply bold css to it.

Comment: Consider adding `font-weight: bold` to the element's style.  See also: [Bold text in the from field: <input>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323508/bold-text-in-the-from-field-input)

Answer (score 0):

text2.style.fontWeight = 'bold';

Answer (score 0):

Here you do not need any css. Bold function Create a  tag .

```
var text1 = "Mind";
var text2 = document.getElementById("t1").value.bold();
var text3 = text1.concat(text2);
document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML = text3;
```

Or You can do this

```
var text1 = "Mind";
var text2 = document.getElementById("t1").value;
document.getElementById("t1").style.fontWeight = "900";
var text3 = text1.concat(text2);
document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML = text3;
```

Comment: Actually, t1 is an input (type: text), that is it is a text box. So the code you mentioned isn't working....

Comment: For what it's worth, MDN says [`bold()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold) is "Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended." But I think `style.fontWeight` should still work for an input element. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6satr1fw/)

Answer (score 0):

In two ways

1.add its style like this:

```
text2.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

2. you can do it setting the `innerHTML` property of the element, just like this:

   ```
    text2.innerHTML = "<b>Hello</b>";
   ```

Comment: Sorry, not working...

Comment: True, `<b>` will not work with an `<input>` because [you can not place any other element within an input element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19236837/924299). But `style.fontWeight` [works](https://jsfiddle.net/6satr1fw/).